# Hibernate connects to wrong database

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jtds

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host/:port/db_name;instance=smth</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">XXX</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">YYY</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
```

With this configuration, hibernate connects my program to "master" database instead of "db_name". How can i solve this problem?

EDIT: jtds 1.2.5.

Comment: just a guess, was this conf really used by your application? do you have other conf (files/jndi/spring beans)? probably you have used the wrong conf name(maven profile/files/jndi/spring beans..), but keep checking the other one?

Comment: Kent, it's really used because if I change something in this conf, it crashes/can't connect to server.

Comment: Problem is solved - SQL Server was configured in a way that we can't use name instances. jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host:port/db_name (without ;instance=smth) is working correctly

Comment: Please, add your answer into Answer Section and correct the same by yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved - SQL Server was configured in a way that we can't use name instances. jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host:port/db_name (without ;instance=smth) is working correctly

Answer (score 1):

Your URL doesn't look right to me.  I don't know if it's a typo, but it should look like this:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host:port/db_name;instance=smth
```

You should not have a slash between host and port.

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat

Comment: Unfortunatly, it doesn't solve this issue, hibernate can't connect to server without slash